# Customizing the URLs of WordPress Login and Sign-up Pages?

Tags: pages, user-registration

I have Multisite installed.  I have whitelabeled it using the Whitelabel-CMS plugin, but I can't customize the URLs of the sign-up and login pages.

Can I change the URL of my multisite's login page?  I want to change the URLs of sign-up, login, and registration pages .

- Sign-up: http://domain.com/wp-signup.php
- Login: http://domain.com/wp-login.php/
- Registration: http://domain.com/wp-register.php/

Could you help me with the customization of these URLs? Is there such possibility?

Update:
I have changed the .htaccess file like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup$ /wp-signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /wp-register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not sure what to do next .

Comment: you can use the stealth login plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stealth-login/

Comment: I have tried it three months ago.I have deactivated it as I am getting some errors If I use it.And the plugin has no updates for a while .

Answer (score 7):

You can use a htaccess file to rename the login and registration addresses to easier to remember versions:

http://wpguy.com/articles/an-easy-to-remember-login-address/

Using what was in that link we can further extend the simple login address into a simple signup and a simple register address as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup$ /wp-signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /wp-register.php [L]
```

Remember these need to go directly after the `RewriteBase /` statement

Comment: I will try this.Is there any chance for errors in the future with any plugins If we replace the URLs?

Comment: I added I added the code to .htaccess file .But there is no change. Am I need to create new files with the new names?

Comment: no you do not need new files, if you had read the page I linked to you'd see that this isnt all you need to do, you need to place them inside the ifmodule section after RewriteBase /

Comment: @user391: Of course, if you add this to your `.htaccess` file, the link `http://www.example.com/login` will be equivalent to `http://www.example.com/wp-login.php`, but WordPress does not know that the nice form exists. So you have to change the *links to the login page* yourself.

Comment: I have changed the htaccess file with the code I updated in this question .But not sure how to proceed further .

Comment: @Jan Fabry You mean the wp-login.php and wp-signup.php files to be renamed?

Comment: nooo, the htaccess rewrites the url so that when the user visits example.com/login they get example.com/wp-login.php instead. Its all apache, nothing to do with wordpress. BUT Wordpress does not know this. The login urls outputted by wordpress will still use example.com/wp-login.php, because you havent told it about the new example.com/login in your wordpress theme.

Comment: @user391: You don't rename the `wp-login.php` and `wp-signup.php` files, because [they won't survive upgrades](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files), but also because some places might still link to them. You try to change as much *links pointing to these pages* as you can, via filters (like [`site_url`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1909)), so they don't point to `/wp-login.php`, but `/login`.

Comment: @Tom Then how to proceed? I have updated htaccess file replacing with the code as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: then you should have your login links etc, try them out now! Other than that go into your theme where you have any links to the login page and swap them out for the new one

Comment: If you must, use if(is_logged_in()){ /* login link here */ } to replace them, or use filters

Comment: The page URLs are not changed yet .The pages are showing with an error If I use that code .

Comment: heh your using us to do all the work for you, go google and you'll see my example pseudocode was not perfect, it's if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... }, though I wouldnt copy paste that either

Comment: Today ! I got it .I have successfully customised wp-login.php and signup urls .But for wp-admin... If I use admin for wp-admin .The new url Admin is redirecting to wp-admin(Even I entered the URL directly in address bar of browser) and the same wp-admin URL is appearing in window .

Comment: For wp-admin links ...if I edit all links related to wp-admin  in core files .Does it causes any trouble for me in the future?

Comment: yes, it would be completely undone when you next tried to update wordpress, some plugins and themes will also reference wp-admin, I strongly suggest you avoid this and just use admin url rewritting as a handy shortcut instead of trying to change half of wordpress to also use it.

Comment: Can you accept this answer?/Explain why it isn't acceptable?